# A plugin is preventing Eclipse from starting up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It just gives me a blank window, and the splash screen doesn't go away.

I tried running it in a terminal, turns out it's a problematic plugin.

Is there a way to disable that plugin without the GUI?

There's the error log:

```
    [org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/IsWovenTester.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.IsWovenTester' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/IsWovenTester.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.IsWovenTester$WeavingMarker' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[org.eclipse.jdt.core] warning at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/sourceprovider/SourceTransformerAspect.aj:106::0 does not match because declaring type is org.eclipse.jdt.core.IOpenable, if match desired use target(org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit) [Xlint:unmatchedSuperTypeInCall]
    see also: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/SourceRefElement.java:198::0
[org.eclipse.jdt.ui] warning at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/sourceprovider/SourceTransformerAspect.aj:106::0 does not match because declaring type is org.eclipse.jdt.core.ITypeRoot, if match desired use target(org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit) [Xlint:unmatchedSuperTypeInCall]
    see also: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/ASTProvider.java:572::0
[org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/sourceprovider/SourceTransformerAspect.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.sourceprovider.SourceTransformerAspect' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/cuprovider/CompilationUnitProviderAspect.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.cuprovider.CompilationUnitProviderAspect' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[ScalaPlugin] [scalaLibBundle] Found 0 bundles: 
LogFilter.isLoggable threw a non-fatal unchecked exception as follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.isLoggable(Log.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeIsLoggable(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:60)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.util.DefaultLogger.warning(DefaultLogger.scala:46)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaPlugin$$anonfun$3.apply(ScalaPlugin.scala:131)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaPlugin$$anonfun$3.apply(ScalaPlugin.scala:130)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaPlugin.<init>(ScalaPlugin.scala:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.cuprovider.CompilationUnitProviderRegistry.registerProviders(CompilationUnitProviderRegistry.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.cuprovider.CompilationUnitProviderRegistry.getProvider(CompilationUnitProviderRegistry.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.cuprovider.CompilationUnitProviderAspect.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_cuprovider_CompilationUnitProviderAspect$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_cuprovider_CompilationUnitProviderRegistry$getProvider(CompilationUnitProviderAspect.aj:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.init$_aroundBody7$advice(PackageFragment.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment.getCompilationUnit(PackageFragment.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.createCompilationUnitFrom(JavaModelManager.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.create(JavaModelManager.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(JavaCore.java:2622)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1451)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2563)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2536)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1395)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2642)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
[StartupDiagnostics$] startup diagnostics: previous version = 2.0.0.rc01-2_09-201111091447-ce49e0a
[StartupDiagnostics$] startup diagnostics: CURRENT version = 2.0.0.rc01-2_09-201111091447-ce49e0a
[ScalaPlugin] Scala compiler bundle: reference:file:plugins/org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.9.2.r25964-b20111108034957.jar
[org.eclipse.jdt.core] warning at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/sourceprovider/SourceTransformerAspect.aj:106::0 does not match because declaring type is org.eclipse.jdt.core.IOpenable, if match desired use target(org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit) [Xlint:unmatchedSuperTypeInCall]
    see also: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/LocalVariable.java:363::0
[org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/imagedescriptor/ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.imagedescriptor.ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[org.eclipse.jdt.ui] warning at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/sourceprovider/SourceTransformerAspect.aj:106::0 does not match because declaring type is org.eclipse.jdt.core.IOpenable, if match desired use target(org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit) [Xlint:unmatchedSuperTypeInCall]
    see also: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/java/hover/JavadocHover.java:630::0
[org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt] error at org/eclipse/contribution/jdt/itdawareness/ITDAwarenessAspect.aj::0 class 'org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.itdawareness.ITDAwarenessAspect' is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode
[ScalaPlugin] open Ride.java
```

Comment: Has it ever worked before? Which versions of eclipse and the plugin are you using? Have you checked if  the plugin is compliant with your eclipse version? How do you have installed the plugin into eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse 3.7.1, I installed it from inside Eclipse itself using the update site.

Comment: What is it? And why don't you add that information to your question, as well as the plugin name, version, ... Reading comments is hard, so your chances will rise if you edit your question properly.

Comment: I have already solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems something was wrong with the workspace, I moved it, chose another workspace, then imported my projects.

It worked.

Comment: Could you please consider accepting loteck's answer? It seems it helped many people, and even more people are posting the same solution as an answer, polluting this question.

Answer (score 28):

For me it helps to delete a file called `.snap`, in the Eclipse workspace folder:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

For some others, the filename is a changing number with the `.snap` extension, like `0.snap` or `55.snap`.

Comment: Nice. For me, in Luna on OS X, there was no (hidden) `.snap` file in that workspace folder, but the only file there was `52.snap`. Trashing that worked like a charm. (Adding `-clean` to `eclipse.ini` earlier did not help, but that option was still enabled after I trashed the file, so *might* have helped too.)

Comment: ....as for my last comment: today, for me it was called `55.snap` (about 178 MB, and a timestamp from yesterday) and this time I was sure I had no `-clean` option enabled in `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: What's the number about? @Arjan got 55, I got 0?

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer; the OP's own answer is just a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @loteck! This worked for my eclipse kepler version. This answer should be marked as correct & accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Today I found a recipe that got Eclipse starting up again:

Quote:

```
cd .metadata/.plugins
mv org.eclipse.core.resources org.eclipse.core.resources.bak
Start eclipse. (It should show an error message or an empty workspace because no project is found.)
Close all open editors tabs.
Exit eclipse.
rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources (Delete the newly created directory.)
mv org.eclipse.core.resources.bak/ org.eclipse.core.resources (Restore the original directory.)
Start eclipse and start working.
```

According to the author this is just a partial solution, individual projects in the workspace maybe have been damaged and may have to be removed later on. We'll see.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can either switch to another workspace OR delete the .snap file inside your current workspace, for me it's at C:\Users\\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\

Comment: This just combines two older answers?

Answer (score 0):

Please try disabling JDT weaving (in Preferences -> JDT weaving, must restart).

It works for me !

Answer (score -1):

After tempting to clean the Projects(which failed), I have exited eclipse twice and the third time, it worked.

The cause of my issue could be that I tried to re-start twice a Oracle Server on debug mode and the eclipse was stuck for some time and I killed it and then tried to restart it, that's when it failed with that "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor" exception